# How to add new values into a key

Tags: python

I am trying to add new values into a key in a dictionary.

```
d = {'key': 'value1'}
New_values = ['value2','value3']
```

I am trying to make it look like this

```
d = {'key': 'value1','value2','value3'}
```

Comment: What you can do is `{'key': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}`

Comment: how to make the values in a list using for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key in dictionary can hold only single value. The value however, can contain other values. The value can be a list, a tuple, or another dict, as well as a number or a string.

For lists:

```
>>> d = {'key': ['value1']}
>>> d['key'].extend(['value2', 'value3'])
>>> d
{'key': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
```

For dicts:

```
>>> d = {'key': {'key1': 'value1'}}
>>> d['key']['key2'] = 'value2'
>>> d['key']['key3'] = 'value3'
>>> d
{'key': { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2: 'value2', 'key3': 'value3' }}
```

For strings:

```
>>> d = {'key': 'value1'}
>>> new_values = ['value2', 'value3']
>>> d['key'] + ',' + ','.join(new_values)
>>> d
{'key': 'value1,value2,value3' }
```

For tuples:

```
>>> d = {'key': ('value1',)}
>>> d['key'] += ('value2', 'value3')
>>> d
{'key': ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')}
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** `.append()` or `.extend()` to a string because a string is not mutable.

If you want your dictionary value to be able to contain multiple items, it should be a container type such as a list.

The easiest way to do this is just to add the single item as a list in the first place.

```
d = {'key': ['value1']}
New_values = ['value2','value3']

d['key'].extend(New_values)
d
```

Output:

```
{'key': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
```